# YouTube Flash API Video issue

Tags: flash, youtube-api, codec

I am implementing the YouTube API in my flash project. When I run the SWF, it works fine. But when I create an EXE, the video appears jerking in win8. Attached is the screenshot of what I see when I run the EXE. This is happening on Win8 only. Win7 is working fine. [image]

Comment: What happens if you export it as an Air project instead of exe projector?

Comment: When I selected the lower version of flash player in publish setting, its working fine in windows8. Earlier it was 11 and then I have selected it to fp10.

Comment: Looks like a Flash platform issue. You should submit this to Adobe.

Comment: Go to Cnet's download.com and search for K-lite codecs for Windows 8. download and install them and your problems will be solved. When you are installing watch out for the crapware and make sure to uncheck boxes and click the decline buttons. I hope this helped you. this is link http://download.cnet.com/Windows-8-Codecs-Pack/3000-13632_4-75754340.html?tag=mncol;3

Comment: also check out this too http://www.eightforums.com/general-support/27750-windows-8-video-black-screen-only-sound.html

Comment: @Sudarshan, I already tried K-lite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved when I upgraded the flash player.